# Rails - App isn't working in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

My app is working correctly in localhost, but when I push to heroku I'm getting this error:

```
2011-05-31T00:31:58+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/
activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/
dependencies.rb:239:in `require': /app/app/controllers/avaliacaos_controller.rb:40:
syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**

```
class AvaliacaosController < ApplicationController

def new
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile])
  @avaliado = Profile.find(params[:avaliado])
  @projeto = Projeto.find(params[:projeto_id])
  @avaliacao = Avaliacao.new
end


def create
  @profile = Profile.find(current_profile)
  @avaliacao  = Avaliacao.new(params[:avaliacao])
  @projeto = Projeto.find(params[:avaliacao][:projeto_id])
if @avaliacao.save
  flash[:success] = "Avaliação Criada com Sucesso."
  redirect_to @projeto
else
  redirect_to (:back)
end
end


end
```

Comment: What is this line of code? /app/app/controllers/avaliacaos_controller.rb:40

Comment: It looks like you're missing one of your dependencies. Are you sure that you have included all your dependencies in your Gemfile? Are you sure you've committed your Gemfile to the repository and pushed it? And are you sure that the gem is supported by Heroku?

Comment: First: the code in the line is `end`.
Second: I didn't change or added any gem, just made a push and stoped work...

Comment: can you post /app/app/controllers/avaliacaos_controller.rb

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have a similar problem, with the same app/app symptom (only on heroku, on local machine, everything is fine).

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I also have the same problem with a heroku application

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
```

suggests that your file avaliacaos_controller.rb has a mismatched number of 'end's (either too many or too few).

Maybe this isn't appearing locally because the controller is not loaded when the server is loaded, whereas in production it is.  Try running your app locally in such a way that this controller is used and you should see the same error.

Comment: The edit you just added has the controller code and it passes a syntax validation for me, so I'm not sure why the error is occurring.  This is definitely the same version of the file committed and being pushed?

Comment: Yes it is. And I'm using the controller locally and works perfect. On heroku nothing works :/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure heroku has your latest code. Try a "git status" to make sure that it is clean (no files are listed), and then you "git push heroku master"

My hypothesis is that you did not push to heroku, or if you did, then you have not committed code locally.

Comment: I did all of this and I pushed. I opened a ticket but the guy handling take too long and speaks just few words. He also noticed this error and copied me that. Was all I got.

Comment: Why do you think there are two app directories?  /app/app/controllers/ .. that seems very very weird.

Comment: That you have a second app directory? It should be rails_root/app/controllers

Comment: Yeah, but locally I checked and there is no `app/app`

Comment: I think he just called his app 'app' on heroku, it looks like?

but also, it looks like there is no line 40 in the controller he posted.

Comment: @daybreaker excellent point. I still think his code on heroku is not the same as local code

Answer (score -1):

try 
heroku run rake db:migrate