# Rails 3.1 - deployment to Heroku, syntax error in redirect_to call, expecting keyword_end ; works locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, syntax-error

I have an application who works fine locally, but breaks with a syntax error on heroku, on a file whose syntax is successfully verified by my local version of ruby.


The application is a new Rails 3.1 application. It works locally.
I just tried to push it to heroku (first time for this app). I am confident all the code has been committed, and pushed to heroku.
The migration (`heroku run rake db:migrate`) worked.

When I tried to run the application, I got the error page. Here is an extract from the logs. Full logs from the console at the end of this question.

```
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': /app/app/controllers/ios_applications_controller.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ...on_path ( :bundle_identifier => params[:bundle_identifier] )...
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                               ^
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/ios_applications_controller.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ...=> params[:bundle_identifier] ), :notice => "No iOS applicat...
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                               ^
```

Note the `app/app/...` weird path (locally, I don't have this weird structure). This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181958/rails-app-isnt-working-in-heroku) (no helpful answers).

Here is the relevant code of the file `ios_applications_controller.rb`:

```
def show

  @ios_application = IosApplication.find(params[:id]) if (params[:id])
  @ios_application = IosApplication.find_by_application_bundle_identifier(params[:bundle_identifier]) if @ios_application.nil? && params[:bundle_identifier]


  if @ios_application.nil?
      # The line below is the mentioned line (32)
     redirect_to new_ios_application_path ( :bundle_identifier => params[:bundle_identifier] ), :notice => "No iOS application found for #{params[:bundle_identifier]}. Would you like to create it?"

      # This does not work either:
      # redirect_to new_ios_application_path, :bundle_identifier => params[:bundle_identifier], :notice => "No iOS application found for #{params[:bundle_identifier]}. Would you like to create it?"

     return
  end


  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @ios_application }
  end
end
```

A syntax check on the file shows no error:

```
$ ruby -wc app/controllers/ios_applications_controller.rb 
Syntax OK
```

Locally, I am running ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.1.3.
On heroku, I am using the cedar stack:

```
$ heroku stack
   aspen-mri-1.8.6
   bamboo-mri-1.9.2
   bamboo-ree-1.8.7
 * cedar (beta)
```

---

Full logs:

```
$ heroku logs --tail

2012-01-09T21:31:21+00:00 heroku[api]: Add-on add logging:basic by guillaume@macmation.com
2012-01-09T21:31:21+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by guillaume@macmation.com
2012-01-09T21:31:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2012-01-09T21:31:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-01-09T21:31:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 55950`
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.1.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:55950
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': /app/app/controllers/ios_applications_controller.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ...on_path ( :bundle_identifier => params[:bundle_identifier] )...
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                               ^
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/ios_applications_controller.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ...=> params[:bundle_identifier] ), :notice => "No iOS applicat...
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                               ^
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `depend_on'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `require_dependency'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:417:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `each'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `block in eager_load!'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `each'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `eager_load!'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-01-09T21:31:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-01-09T21:31:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-01-09T21:31:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2012-01-09T21:41:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2012-01-09T21:41:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-01-09T21:41:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In production, a space seems to not be allowed between the method name and the opening parenthesis.

```
redirect_to new_ios_application_path ( ... # Invalid syntax
redirect_to new_ios_application_path( ...  # Ok (no space after new_ios_application_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think line#32 has syntax error

```
redirect_to new_ios_application_path ( :bundle_identifier => params[:bundle_identifier] ), :notice => "No iOS application found for #{params[:bundle_identifier]}. Would you like to create it?"
```

should be

```
redirect_to(new_ios_application_path(:bundle_identifier => params[:bundle_identifier] , :notice => "No iOS application found for #{params[:bundle_identifier]}. Would you like to create it?"))
```

also use **and** with return to return avoid next execution as follow

```
redirect_to(new_ios_application_path(:bundle_identifier => params[:bundle_identifier]), :notice => "No iOS application found for #{params[:bundle_identifier]}. Would you like to create it?")) and return
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, the new syntax does not cause any error, but it does not seem to be what I need. I want the notice text to be shown on next screen. With this new syntax, it only pass it as a parameter. And I still do not understand why the code is working locally but not on heroku, and why the syntax error did not show up with ruby -wc check?

Comment: oh, the notice should be passed to redirect_to not url here is the code:
`redirect_to(new_ios_application_path(:bundle_identifier => params[:bundle_identifier]), :notice => "No iOS application found for #{params[:bundle_identifier]}. Would you like to create it?")) and return`

Comment: Ok, a space is not allowed between the method name and the opening parenthesis. Did not know that. I guess it's the different environment that produces a different behavior.

Comment: Please, edit your answer so I can accept it (right now, it will be confusing to future readers, because the stated answer is wrong, and the working one is hidden in the comments. And I didn't understand what you mean by the use of and. The return on a new line works the same way.

Comment: You did not explain what you said about the "and return". And please, make it more explicit about the un-allowed space. Even after reading your answer, I had to troubleshoot a lot to find out what exactly the problem.